# Flex Error on Simple Custom Event when Implemented in Actionscript (But not in MXML)

Tags: apache-flex, custom-events

I'm trying to learn how to use custom events in Flex.

I'm following Oliver Merk's tutorial found here: [blog](http://blog.olivermerk.ca/index.cfm/2007/5/24/Flex-Custom-Events--Part-II)

The custom event works if I implement it using MXML in the main app. But, if I use actionscript, then I get error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property ADD_PRODUCT through a reference with static type Class.

My Event:
In the events subdirectory, I've got:

```
package events {

   import flash.events.Event;

   public class AddProductEvent extends Event {

      public var productName:String;

      public function AddProductEvent( type:String, productName:String ) {

         super( type );
         this.productName = productName;

      }

      override public function clone():Event {
         return new AddProductEvent( type, productName );
      }

   }
}
```

In the component, I've got a radioButtonGroup

```
<mx:RadioButtonGroup id="choicesRadioButtonGroup" itemClick="onButtonClick()"/>



private function onButtonClick():void {
            var myEventObj:Event = new AddProductEvent("addProduct", "Flex T-shirt");
            dispatchEvent(myEventObj);
        }
```

This is the metadata in the component and the import statement:

```
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event (name="addProduct", type="events.AddProductEvent")]
</mx:Metadata>

import events.AddProductEvent;
```

In the main app, I've got:

```
import events.AddProductEvent;

private function onAddProduct( event:AddProductEvent ):void {
mx.controls.Alert.show('Attached data was ' + event.productName);
}
```

If I implement the component in the main app like this:

```
<visualcomponent:PopWindow addProduct="onAddProduct(event)" />
```

then everything works.

If I implement the component in the main app in actionscript like this, then I get an error:

```
public function clickHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {

    if(event.currentTarget.selected){popWindow = new PopWindow;
        queryBuilder(event.currentTarget);
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(popWindow, my_view, false);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popWindow);

            popWindow.addEventListener(AddProductEvent.ADD_PRODUCT, onAddProduct);}

    }
```

I get the error on the addEventListener line. What am I doing wrong? Any advice?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AddProductEvent class doesn't seem to expose a public static string called ADD_PRODUCT which has the value "addProduct" which is what it looks like you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Gregor Kiddie, Thank you for your message. I'm still learning about custom events. I don't understand what I need to change. I'm trying to have my event send the productName string back to the main app. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I added public static const ADD_PRODUCT:String = "addProduct"; in the event after  public class AddProductEvent extends Event {... and now it works. Thank you!